# fifo read sometimes will block

Tags: c, block, ipc, fifo

I am writing a IPC assignment. In the server side, I use popen to execute ls and write the result into fifo for client to read. I thought everything is going good, but sometimes if I type the command very fast the client will be stuck. I have not idea will that happened.

client:

```
else if(memcmp(cmd, CMD_REMOTE_DIR, strlen(CMD_REMOTE_DIR)) == 0){
        if(write(client_writer_fifo_fd, cmd, strlen(cmd)) == -1){
            perror("write cmd ERROR");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        for(;;){
            memset(read_buffer,0,sizeof(read_buffer));
            num_read = read(client_reader_fifo_fd, read_buffer,
                    sizeof(read_buffer));
            if(num_read < 0){
                perror("Read dir ERROR");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
            if(num_read == 0)
                break;
            //read_buffer[strlen(read_buffer)] = '\0';
            printf("%s",read_buffer);

        }
    }
```

server:

```
else if(memcmp(read_buffer, CMD_REMOTE_DIR,
                            strlen(CMD_REMOTE_DIR)) == 0){
                    fp = popen(CMD_LS_POPEN, "r");
                    if(fp == NULL){
                        perror("popen fail");
                        continue;
                    }
                    while(fgets(write_buffer,sizeof(write_buffer),fp)
                            != NULL){
                        if(write(client_reader_fifo_fd, write_buffer
                                    ,strlen(write_buffer)) == -1)
                            perror("write dir ERROR");
                    }
                    close(client_reader_fifo_fd);
                    pclose(fp);

                }
```

Comment: Do not use `fgets`. read by char. and better use `read`, and not stdio.

Comment: @ValeriAtamaniouk, why?  POSIX I/O and C stdio should not be mixed on the same file, but there's nothing inherently wrong with using them for different files in the same program.  And whyever would it be a better idea to read one char at a time?

Comment: @JohnBollinger stdio operates with buffered operations. And logic for buffering is not explicitly specified. So overall, the approach would be more complex: even when requesting a single character, the lower-level may block on buffer fill.

Comment: @ValeriAtamaniouk, buffering is not the issue here (though the stream provided by `popen()` will indeed be buffered), and the particular use of `fgets()` is not going to be a problem.  The `fgets()` in any case cannot be replaced by `read()`, because the program has only a stream pointer, not a file handle.

Comment: @zhengzhou, add logging to try to determine where the client is hanging.  It might be, for instance, that it hangs opening the FIFO rather than while trying to read from it.

Comment: @JohnBollinger see `fileno`.

Comment: @zhengzhou, your client does have an issue with unterminated strings.  For your read to be safe, it must be certain to leave room for the terminator: `read(..., sizeof(read_buffer) - 1)`.  Also, it's pretty inefficient to clear the whole buffer every time.  Better to `read_buffer[num_read] = '\0'` after each `read()`.

Comment: Ah, yes, `fileno()`.  I tend to ignore it because it is not standard C (it is specified by POSIX).  Since the program uses POSIX I/O already, though, another POSIXism couldn't hurt.  Of course, it's unlikely to help, either.